# html5 input regex pattern that cannot neither start nor ends with SPACE?

Tags: regex, html

what would be the html5 input regex pattern so input cannot neither start nor ends with SPACE ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj why would you need to use lookbehind?

Comment: @lis alternative `^(?=\S).*\S$`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I guess what I'm trying to ask is why not just use this: `^\S.*\S$` ?

Comment: Because your regex should fail if the input is `a` , this starts and ends with a non-space character. That's why I used lookarounds:-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj realized just before your reply! Thank you :) Definitely not something that I took into immediate consideration.

Comment: Could just do ^(\S|\S.*?\S)$ in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this positive lookahead based regex.

```
^(?=\S).*\S$
```

- `^(?=\S)` asserts that there must be a non-space character exists at the start.
- `.*` any char zero or more times.
- `\S$` must contain a non-space character at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an alternative without look-ahead:

```
^\S(.*\S)?$
```

Do note that `.` doesn't match line separator characters. However, I don't think `input` support multiline text.